# Как распаковать архив gz при помощи 7-zip в GUI приложении на Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, gzip

Гуглил по поводу 7z.dll, но нормальной документации не нашёл, лишь парочку примеров и ничего такого, читал сами исходники 7-zip'a, но тоже мало понял.

Comment: Вызывайте приложение-распаковщик в `QProcess`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решение:
Взял из папки с установленным 7-zip файла `zip.exe`, положил его в папку билда приложения `build-zipping-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug` (кто не знает для приложение, запускаемого из Qt Creatora это рабочая папка).
Приложение Qt-Консоль, добавил класс `MainClass`, наследовался от `QObject`.

**mainclass.h**

```
#ifndef MAINCLASS_H
#define MAINCLASS_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QProcess>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QFile>


class MainClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MainClass(QObject *parent = 0);

signals:

private slots:
    void started();
    void finished(int arg1, QProcess::ExitStatus status);
private:
    void unzip(QString pathName);
    QProcess *zipp;
};

#endif // MAINCLASS_H
```

**mainclass.cpp**

```
#include "mainclass.h"

MainClass::MainClass(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    this->unzip("test.gz");
}

void MainClass::started()
{
    qDebug() << this->zipp->program() << " " << this->zipp->arguments();
}

void MainClass::finished(int arg1,QProcess::ExitStatus status)
{
    QByteArray result = this->zipp->readAll();
    qDebug() << result.data();
    qDebug() << "exitCode: " << this->zipp->exitCode() << " arg1: "  << arg1 << " status: "  << status;
    QFile file("log.txt");
}

void MainClass::unzip(QString pathName)
{
    this->zipp = new QProcess(this);
    QString program = "zip.exe";

    connect(this->zipp, SIGNAL(started()),
            this, SLOT(started()));
    connect(this->zipp, SIGNAL(finished(int,QProcess::ExitStatus)),
            this, SLOT(finished(int,QProcess::ExitStatus)));

    QStringList arguments;
    arguments
            << "e"
            << pathName
            << "-o./";
    this->zipp->start(program, arguments);
}
```

Comment: Неужели нельзя обойтись парой строк snprintf/system ?

Comment: Зависит от задачи, для примера вполне, а вот в реальных задачах приходится делать что-то более.

Comment: Ну, 2 строчки это для примера. Понятно, что надо проверить коды возврата. Но результат-то тот же -- распаковка архива на диске.

Comment: Пример расчитан на всех, а если у человека какая-то непонятная ошибка появится, а он раз и коды посмотрел, я всегда стараюсь рассчитывать на самую плохую ситуацию.

Comment: На мой вкус это просто занудно, но в конце-концов код Ваш. Пишите как хотите.

Answer (score 2):

Лучшее решение предложил @aleks.andr, но можно попытаться собрать 7-Zip из состава [Qt-фреймворка для разработки инсталляторов](https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/admin/projects/installer-framework/installer-framework). Судя по всему, код 7-Zip там интегрирован полностью.

Comment: Решение @aleks.andr лучше расписать чуть подробнее